# Replace {tag} with a value or completely remove {any-tag}

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I've designed a multilingual web site and some values in database have a tag which will be replaced with it's language value, remove tags brackets ( in case {} ) or removed completely.

There are two cases:

Remove brackets:

```
value {mm} >> value mm
```

Remove completely:

```
value {mm} >> value
```

Also {tag} could be any length and can contain -

Can anybody help me with regex?

Comment: Is there a question here?  I can't tell if you're looking to pre-process the pages, advice on how to internationalize with resource files or what.

Comment: I just need regular expression to replace {mm} to mm or completely remove {mm}

Comment: To add to what @48klocs said, ASP.NET already provides a way to handle multiple language elements if your website is supposed to cater to different cultures and languages. It would be much cleaner than a bunch of if/else statements and replacing values from a database. If you're interested do some research on ASP.NET *globalization* and *localization*. This process can also be referred to as *internationalization*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code you might find useful. For many *many* more options, see [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

All code `Using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

---

Remove all occurrences of `{mm}` (and *only* `mm`):

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "{mm}", String.Empty, RegexOptions.None);
```

---

Replace all occurrences of `{mm}` (and *only* `mm`) with `mm`:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "{mm}", "mm", RegexOptions.None);
```

---

Remove all occurrences of `{any-characters}`:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"{[\-a-z]*}", String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

Replace all occurrences of `{any-characters}` with `any-characters`:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"{(?<tag>[\-a-z]*)}", "${tag}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: @cyclotis04: Regular expressions are new to me and I think they are not easy to understand. I've visited this site before but I needed fast solution. This is why I ask here. But thanks for the advice ;)

Also stackoverflow is like an archive for me. So if I need same thing in future, here I look first :)

Comment: @HasanGursoy: Yes, there's definitely nothing regular about them. If you find that one of the solutions I gave doesn't do what you want, tell me what went wrong, and I can try and help you out with a more specific Regular Expression. =]

Comment: @Hasan: I can also recommend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: @cyclotis04: I'm getting "parsing "{(?[\-a-z]*)}" - Unrecognized grouping construct." error with the last one. Probably using result.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty); will do the same.

Comment: @Hasan @cyclotis probably meant `{([\-a-z]*)}` (remove the `?`). BTW, the `-` need not be escaped within the character class but be sure to place it at either the beginning or end of the class as shown to prevent unintended character range specifications. Keeping it escaped does no harm of course, just an FYI.

Comment: @Ahmad: Correct - or, you can add a group name, like `tag` (which I did.) For some reason I tried to find a middle ground between naming it and not naming it. =P

Comment: @Hasan: `result.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty);` would get rid of **ALL** the brackets, which *may* be what you want. If you want to get rid of only some of them, Regular Expressions are the way to go.

Comment: @cyclotis naming is definitely clearer. Usually if a small number of groups are involved it's not too hard to follow as long as they aren't nested, otherwise naming them is much better. BTW your named group syntax in the replacement string needs to be `${tag}` not `$tag`. For numbered groups it's `$n` but for named groups it's `${group-name}`.

Comment: @Ahmad: You're right, you're right... It's been too long of not working with Regex's... >.<

Answer (score 0):

.Net already provides a similar functionality using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

```
string.Format("value {0}", ""); // returns "value "
string.Format("value {0}", "some value"); // returns "value some value"
```

You can do more advanced things with this method, such as specifying formatting for numbers:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "value {0:N}", 10000); // returns 10,000.00
string.Format(new CultureInfo("es-ES"), "value {0:N}", 10000); // returns 10.000,00
```

The two downsides to this method:

1. No case for removing the brackets.
2. Can't name your placeholders. You have to use ordinal placeholders. {0}, {1}...{n}.

Comment: Nice but not exactly what I need. I need to know what to replace with the tag. For example there are tags like {power-source}. I cannot replace all zeros with its language label. Also it's not user friendly.