# Replace characters === either side of text with html tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm really struggling to find a way of getting the following to work, I have some data in the following format ===some text=== I want to replace the === around the text with html tags.

I've tried using [Match and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899794/match-and-replace), but I get a bad compile constant value, I have also tried [Replace {tag} with a value or completely remove {any-tag}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922730/replace-tag-with-a-value-or-completely-remove-any-tag?rq=1) but that just removes all the text. I have also tried http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html but none work, I think the problem I'm having is because the tags around the text do not have closing tags I'm unable to find the text

So I have tried something like this:

```
string format = Regex.Replace(data.FirstOrDefault().countrylist, "=== This could be any text ===", " </p><p class=\"strong\">Need to keep text here<p>");
```

example of how the text looks:

====Rise and fall of the Roman empire====

====20th and 21st centuries====

So I would want it to look:

```
</p><p class=\"strong\">Rise and fall of the Roman empire<p>
</p><p class=\"strong\">20th and 21st centuries<p>
```

I'm not the greatest at regular expressions, and all my attempts have failed so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the input text delimited in any way? Each phrase is on a new line?

Comment: You have strange closing paragraph tag at the beginning of line, and unclosed paragraph at the end

Comment: Without regex it would be: find first occurrence of `===`, replace it with opening tag `<p blablabla>`, find second occurance of `===`, replace it with closing tag `</p>`.

Comment: Hi Alex string is over 33000 characters long and the phrase can occur multiple times within the string, the === remains the same but text changes inside

Comment: Hi @Sergey Berezovskiy I have added <p> at start of string and </p> at end

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson ... FYI, your question shows both === (first sentence) and ==== (examples) as delimiters.  You may want to edit to clarify. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var yourstring = "===20th and 21st centuries===";
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("==="));
// The last 1 tells to replace only the first occurence of the Escape
yourstring = regex.Replace(yourstring, "</p><p class=\"strong\">", 1);
yourstring = regex.Replace(yourstring, "<p>", 1);
```

Do not forget the error handling, I don't exactly know what happens if it wants to replace an occurence and can't find it

Edit: If you have multiple entries which should be replaced, loop the replace part until it will not be able to replace anymore then it will throw an error you can catch to continue

Answer (score 0):

The following worked in my environment:

```
    string text = "===Rise and fall of the Roman empire===";
    var pattern = @"===(.*)===";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var match = regex.Match(text);
    var result = string.Concat("</p><p class=\"strong\">", match.Groups[1].Value, "<p>");
```

Regards,

Comment: try with this string: ` "===Rise and fall of the Roman empire=== some other text ===Rise and fall of the Roman empire===";`

Comment: In the example, the question seemed to indicate (and my answer was geared toward) a simple single occurrence. If the text was more like your proposed string, then the pattern above would need to change (perhaps something like (@"===([^={3}]*)===") and the regex.Match would need to become regex.Matches ...